# Apache .htaccess redirect if folder not present

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a website where I need to do the following

if http://example.com/user1 does not exist, redirect the user to http://user1.example.com

Similarly http://www.example.com/user2 should redirect to http://user2.example.com

Is this possible using an .htaccess file?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R]
```

The above redirects to the home page, but how do I read the URL after / and do the redirect as above?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your example.com site.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 

#if on example.com host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
#and the directory/folder does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#redirect to folder.example.com
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ http://$1.%{HTTP_HOST} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com      # prevent infinite redirection
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule .* http://%1.%{SERVER_NAME} [R]
```

The somewhat cumbersome regex on `REQUEST_URI` ensures, only URLs of the `http://example.com/user1` scheme will be redirected (as opposed to `/user1/foo/bar`).

Note the use of `SERVER_NAME` instead of `HTTP_HOST` (the latter [is evil and should be avoided](http://perfect-co.de/2011/02/why-http_host-is-evil/)).